# mysql timediff is 12 hours off

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out a bug in my timeclock query.  The breakin punch is at 12pm and the breakout punch is at 12:30pm.  I calculate the difference using timediff in mysql.  I pass in the breakout time followed by the breakin time to the timediff function.  It is returning the correct minutes, but it is also returning -12 hours.  And when I swap the breakin and breakout in the timediff function, it returns a positive 12 hours with the correct minutes.

I figured somebody might want to see the query.  Warning: it is big and ugly.
Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
               U.EmpID AS 'Empl ID',
               DATE_FORMAT(U.`time`, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
               DATE_FORMAT(U.`time`, '%W') AS 'Weekday',
               TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(U.delta)), '%H:%i') AS 'Time Worked',
               TIME_FORMAT(
                  TIMEDIFF(
                     (SELECT PunchDateTime
                        FROM timeclock_punchlog tp
                       WHERE     PunchEvent = 'breakout'
                             AND DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) = DATE(U.time)
                             AND tp.EmpID = U.EmpID), 
                     (SELECT PunchDateTime
                        FROM timeclock_punchlog tp
                       WHERE     PunchEvent = 'breakin'
                             AND DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) = DATE(U.time)
                             AND tp.EmpID = U.EmpID)),
                  '%h hrs, %i min.')
                  AS Lunch
                FROM ((SELECT `enter`.EmpID,
                           `enter`.PunchDateTime AS `time`,
                           DATE_FORMAT(`enter`.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y')
                              AS 'Punch Date',
                           TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                                         `enter`.PunchDateTime,
                                         '2003-05-01 00:00:00')
                              AS `delta`
                      FROM timeclock_punchlog AS `enter`
                     WHERE `enter`.`In-Out` = 1)
                   UNION
                   (SELECT `leave`.EmpID,
                           `leave`.PunchDateTime AS `time`,
                           DATE_FORMAT(`leave`.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y')
                              AS 'Punch Date',
                           -TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                                          `leave`.PunchDateTime,
                                          '2003-05-01 00:00:00')
                              AS `delta`
                      FROM timeclock_punchlog AS `leave`
                     WHERE `leave`.`In-Out` = 0)) AS U
               LEFT JOIN prempl pe ON u.EmpID = pe.prempl
        WHERE DATE(U.`time`) >= "2015-10-05"
        AND DATE(U.`time`) <= "2015-10-07"
        AND U.EmpID = 0349
        GROUP BY date(U.`time`), EmpID
        ORDER BY U.EmpID, U.`time` ASC
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65b18/1) that reproduces the issue with a simple query.

```
insert into times values 
    ('12:30 pm','12:00 pm'),
    ('12:00 pm','12:30 pm');

select time_format(timediff(start,end),'%h hrs, %i min.') from times
```

Result:

```
12 hrs, 30 min.
-12 hrs, 30 min.
```

And here is a sql fiddle using datetime type and produces same results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fb73/1

Comment: It is hard to see how this could be anything other than a bug.

Comment: So you are saying it is a bug in the mysql timediff function?

Comment: @dmikester1 cloud you please check the timezone setting; it might a problem.

Comment: @akm in mysql?  is there a way to set the timezone before running a query in mysql?  I'm not sure why that would matter.

Comment: @dmikester1 Timezone could be problem; if your SQL Client code and server code resides on two different machine then in interfacing you can have such issue which I assume is not that case with you. Now looking at your SQL fiddle I see that you are using `char` datatype to store `time` are you doing the same in your other table ?

Comment: @akm, I added the SQL Fiddle to OP's question to try to show the problem more simply.  Sorry if this added confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the way are formatting time; see if the difference is negative you get into such trouble.

Also there are few limitations with `time_format` I would recommend reading the MySQL documentation on it.

As per last communication; I assume that you are using a `datetime` data type then the following query will work.

```
CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `PunchID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `breakout` datetime NOT NULL,
  `breakin` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PunchID`)
);

insert into `times` 
values (1,'2015-10-06 12:00:00', '2015-10-06 12:30:00');
```

Select query (Note the change in format string `h` changed to `H`)

```
select time_format(timediff(breakin,breakout),'%H hrs, %i min.') from times;
```

and everything works correctly.

A bit of advice if you are not sure which column may have greater value than the other columns doing a `timediff` and formatting it can give you bizarre results better use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in such cases and work on integer maths.

Documentation on [MySQL date and time functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly feed a time string like `'12:30 pm'` into MySQL. The `am / pm` part will always be ignored. Try to use the 24h format instead.

Comment: Actually @dmikester1 is using the `char` data type instead of `time` that is why MySQL is allowing such feeding and resulting into a bad result.

Comment: No, I am using a datetime type for my table.  The person who created the fiddle entered it as a char.

Comment: added a fiddle using datetime type and no am/pm to op.  it produces same results